Yet another question about Riemann sums
It is well known that if $f:]0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotonic and if the improper integral $\int_0^1f(t)\,dt$ converges, then :
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1f(t)\,dt$$
There are counter-examples showing that this conclusion is lost without the hypothesis that $f$ is monotonic. See here
My question : is it possible that the above integral converges and that the sequence $(S_n)$ converges to a limit $L\neq\int_0^1f(t)\,dt$ ?
EDIT : How is the above question affected when restricting $f$ to the class of continuous functions ?

You may need to be more precise in the space where $f$ lives. If you are restricted to measurable functions and Lebesgue integral, then the indicator function of irrational numbers is a simple counter example.

@LPZ You're absolutely right. I will try to rephrase ...

I will assume we are taking Lebesgue integrals since such an $f$ is clearly not Riemann integrable. If we let $f$ be discontinuous then we can just take the indicator function for the rationals as a trivial example. If we require $f$ to be continuous, then it must be unbounded. An example of such an $f$ is given below.
Let $T(x)=\max(1-|x|,0)$ be the triangle function. Define $$
f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)\\ 
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=2}^n a_kT\left(k^3\left(x-\frac1k\right)\right)\\ a_n = n-\sum_{k=1}^nf_{n-1}\left(\frac kn\right)$$ recursively (we start from $f_1(x)=0$). Then for all $n >1$, $$S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right)=1$$ On the other hand, since $a_k\leq k$, $$\int_0^1 a_kT\left(k^3\left(x-\frac 1k\right)\right)dx=\frac{a_k}{k^3}\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1<1,$$ so we see that the integral and sequence converge to distinct values.
